# SVM ensemble with logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, svm, ensemble-learning, model-averaging

It is possible to average several logistic models in a ensemble using the estimated probabilities of the models.

Does it make sense to calculate an ensemble based on the raw SVM score, i.e. the distance to the hyperplane?

Comment: It depends on how you do it.   "Average" won't work, since the raw SVM score isn't a probability and won't even be on a 0-1 scale like a probability.   Stacking would likely be better - using the various numbers as an input to a subsequent model.